# I can't make a redirection in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I try to make a redirection in wordpress to change the page when the website is viewed by a mobile device. (I don't want wp-touch). The target page is external to wordpress.

I added this code in the header.php wordpress file:

```
//test if it is a mobile device
...

if ($mobile_browser > 0) {

    wp_redirect('Location: http://url-to-my-external-page' ); 
    exit;
}
```

I also tried in the index.php file but it doesn't work either.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? If it's just not redirecting, could you post your "//test if it is a mobile device" code? That might be the problem. You could troubleshoot this yourself by echoing out the value of $mobile_browser, even it is to the js console.

Comment: The code for //test ... is too long but I'm sure it works, I tested it on a standalone page. Anyway I'm not getting any error but the code I put on top of the header.php is just NOT executed. A simple echo doesn't appear... I don't know

Comment: Have you placed the echo before your "if" statement? Have you checked that you are adding this code in the right header.php? (should be wp-content/themes/default/)

Comment: Of course the echo is the first line of the file after <?php and I'm in the right header.php

Comment: Have you edited the code through the Wordpress editor or through FTP? I suggest you triple check this as it is very likely you are editing the wrong file. Also, may I suggest you post Wordpress questions in more suitable environment such as: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Through FTP. Thank you very much, I'm gonna do that. Finally I managed to modify the root index.php. But modifying the index.php or header.php inside the theme folder didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing PHP's [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function and WordPress' [`wp_redirect()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) function.

It's either:

```
header('Location: http://url-to-my-external-page');
```

or

```
wp_redirect('http://url-to-my-external-page');
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
wp_redirect('url-to-my-external-page'); // without "Location:"
```